# Can't access image file from src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resources/img in controller to display in jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I try to display images from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resources/img/` folder (different from `src/main/resources`)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/items")
public class ItemsController {
    @GetMapping( "/images/{itemId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getItemImageById(@PathVariable long itemId) throws IOException {
           BufferedImage originalImage =
                ImageIO.read(
            new File("/WEB-INF/resources/img/" + itemId + ".png"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write( originalImage, "png", baos );
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        return imageInByte;
    }
}
```

```
<img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/items/images/1'/>
```

It doesn't work - no image, but if I replace the path in the `File` constructor with absolute path like this: `C://.../some_file.png` it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot go through a "File" to read in your image you need to go through the **ServletContext**.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/items")
public class ItemsController {

   @Autowired
   ServletContext context;

    @GetMapping( "/images/{itemId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getItemImageById(@PathVariable long itemId) throws IOException {
           BufferedImage originalImage =
                ImageIO.read(context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/resources/img/" + itemId + ".png"));

        // your original code
    }
}
```

Comment: Also what do you think of the other approach (a second answer)?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that worked for me is:

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

Resource resource =  resourceLoader.getResource(
                "/WEB-INF/resources/img/" + itemId + ".png");
String path = resource.getFile().getPath();
return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
```

Comment: That ResourceLoader will be a ServletContextResourceLoader and do exactly the same as you did manunally: use the servletcontext to get the resource. As for converting to a file: This will work with expanded war.files , but not with un-expanded ones and it is an unneccesary step, as you can get the InputStream directly without going through files.